# How can I switch styles dynamically in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I have one `styles.css` and another `styles-highcontrast.css`, both of them essentially contain the same styles but the later adaptations for people with sight issues.
The `styles-highcontrast.css` is set to `lazy` in the angular.json.

How can I switch between the two with just a click of a button?

Thanks

Comment: Why not apply a different class to your body ?

Comment: user Scss it will make so easy for you if you trying theming in app

Answer (score 0):

Have your high-contrast css wrapped in some specific class, e.g.:

```
a {color: red;}

.high-contrast a {color: extraRed;}
```

And in HTML:

```
<body ng-class="{'high-contrast': vm.useHighContrast}">
    <button ng-click="vm.useHighContrast = !vm.useHighContrast">Switch contrast</button>
```

Comment: he is using angular6 so I guess it will be `ngClass` instead of `ng-class` and `(click)` instead of `ng-click`.

Comment: @SlimenTN Sorry, still using AngularJS, but idea is the same

Comment: Yeah no problem your answer is correct just corrected the syntax :)